# Which tense can I use?

Tags: verb-usage

Which is correct:

> "I think you should go on a diet.You are **putting** on weight."

or

> "I think you should go on a diet. You **have put** on weight."

Comment: Why do you think only one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your sentences are correct and understandable, both mean the person has gained weight in the past.

"Putting" implies the person *at this moment* is still gaining weight, "have put" means the person has already gained whatever weight they were going to gain.